# Linker error for non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, linker-errors, non-type

all.

I made a set of c++ codes as follows.
Then, I compiled each `.cpp` to `.o` by g++, successfully.
However, I got a linkage error as

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "derive1<3>::derive1(int)", referenced from:
      derive2::derive2(int)in derive2.o
      derive2::derive2(int)in derive2.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Could you tell me what's happening?  If I bind all the code snippets in one file, I have not got any errors, and it works perfectly as I intended.  I assume I should introduce extern keyword somewhere but I don't know how to do that.

My compiler is

> i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc.
>   build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)

"base.hpp"

```
class base {
public:
  virtual int hoge( int num ) = 0;

};
```

"derive1.hpp"

```
#include "base.hpp"
#include <iostream>

template <int N>
class derive1 : public base {
public:
  explicit derive1( int n );
  virtual int hoge( int num ) {
    std::cout << "num = " << num << std::endl
          << "N = " << N << std::endl;
    return N;
  }    

};
```

"derive1.cpp"

```
#include "derive1.hpp"

template <int N>
derive1<N>::derive1 ( int n ) {
  std::cout << "This is the constructer of derive1" << std::endl
        << "N = " << N << ", n = " << n << std::endl;
}
```

"derive2.hpp"

```
#include "derive1.hpp"
#include <iostream>

class derive2 : public derive1<3> {
public:
  explicit derive2( int n );
};
```

"derive2.cpp"

```
#include "derive2.hpp"

derive2::derive2( int n ) : derive1<3>( n ) {
  std::cout << "This is the constructer of derive2" << std::endl
        << "n = " << n << std::endl;
}
```

"derive_test.cpp"

```
#include<iostream>
#include "derive2.hpp"

int main() {

  derive2 test(3);

  std::cout << "return value = "
        << test.hoge( 5 )
        << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The same problem is solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152002/how-do-i-force-a-particular-instance-of-a-c-template-to-instantiate

Comment: Oops.  Sorry for my search ability.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get "unresolved external symbol" errors when using templates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456713/why-do-i-get-unresolved-external-symbol-errors-when-using-templates)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't split definition and implementation for .h and .cpp files for template classes.

[What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix/12574417#12574417)

Comment: Thanks!  It works.  And, the link is very useful for me.  Now, I should use the Pimpl idiom.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, most compilers require that the implementation of the template function (in this case the `template <int N> derive1<N>::derive1 ( int n )` is available to the compile unit using it. Move it to "derive1.hpp".

Comment: Thanks.  I bought a lot of books of C++ but still feel lack of this kind of information.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that you have to put all the templated code (`derive1::derive1(int)` etc.) into the header files, not into their own translation units. The compiler needs to see the full definition when it tries to instantiate the template. Of course, you *can* have the definition for a template in the `*.cpp` file, but then you have to explicitly specilalize it and also declare that specialization in the header file.