# "template<>" vs "template" without brackets - what's the difference?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Suppose I've declared:

```
template <typename T> void foo(T& t);
```

Now, what is the difference between

```
template <> void foo<int>(int& t);
```

and

```
template void foo<int>(int& t);
```

semantically? And do template-with-no-brackets and template-with-empty-brackets have other semantics in other contexts?

---

<sub>Related to: 
[How do I force a particular instance of a C++ template to instantiate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2152002/1593077)</sub>

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`template <> void foo<int>(int& t);` declares a **specialization** of the template, with potentially different body.

`template void foo<int>(int& t);` causes an **explicit instantiation** of the  template, but doesn't introduce a specialization. It just forces the instantiation of the template for a specific type.

Comment: That is quite confusing! I assume the meaning of the declaration is that the compiler will not accept the instantiation of the unspecialized template as a candidate, when the specialized definition is not found?

Comment: Explaining this a bit more: the first one can be used in a header file and it says "`foo<int>` will have a different body to `foo<T>`" ; if code elsewhere in the program calls `foo<int>()` but you don't provide the body then you should get alink error.

Comment: The second one should not be used in a header file; using it in one .cpp file makes sure that the body of `foo<int>` (which uses the `foo<T>` template to generate it unless you also had the specialization line!) is actually processed (It's somewhat like *defining* a non-template function) .  Normally you don't need to do this as it happens whenever some other code calls `foo<int>` , but you might want to do it [for a few reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351148/explicit-instantiation-when-is-it-used)

Comment: It's less confusing if you see the <> as a special case of an empty template parameter list. In general, you use this syntax to create (**possibly partial**) specializations. If it happens to not have any parameters (that is, not partial) it gives you that syntax. You are still declaring *a template*.

Comment: @jdlugosz: I was under the impression that partial specialization is not supoorted...

Answer (score 13):

With class/struct,

```
template <typename T> struct foo {};
```

Following is a specialization:

```
template <> struct foo<int>{};
```

Following is an explicit instantiation:

```
template struct foo<int>;
```