# Using function-templated code across the g++-nvcc boundary (including kernels)

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, cuda, explicit-instantiation

Suppose I compile the following with NVIDIA CUDA's nvcc compiler:

```
template<typename T, typename Operator>
__global__ void fooKernel(T t1, T t2)  {
    Operator op;
    doSomethingWith(t1, t2);
}

template<typename T>
__device__ __host__ void T bar(T t1, T t2)  {
    return t1 + t2;
}

template<typename T, typename Operator>
void foo(T t1, T t2)  {
    fooKernel<<<2, 2>>>(t1, t2);
}

// explicit instantiation
template decltype(foo<int, bar<int>>) foo<int, bar<int>);
```

Now, I want my gcc, non-nvcc code to call `foo()`:

```
...

template<typename T, typename Operator> void foo(T t1, T t2);


foo<int, bar<int>> (123, 456);
...
```

I have the appropriate (?) instantiation in the .o/.a/.so file I compile with CUDA.

Can I make that happen?

Comment: Why is `bar` defined twice in the first snippet? And what is the real question here? Why would you want to apply the `decltype` keyword (if it is supported in CUDA which I'm not sure about) in a `void`function that doesn't return a value? What are you expecting that will achieve?

Comment: @talonmies: 1. mis-copy-paste.  2.  See  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28354752/template-vs-template-without-brackets-whats-the-difference); that will achieve an explicit instantiation. Will clear it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that templated code is typically instantiated at the place of usage, which doesn't work because `foo` contains a kernel call which cannot be parsed by g++. Your approach of explicitly instantiating the template and forward declaring it for the host compiler is the right one. Here's how to do this. I slightly fixed up your code and split it into 3 files:

1. gpu.cu
2. gpu.cuh
3. cpu.cpp

#### gpu.cuh

This file contains the templated code for use by `gpu.cu`. I added some purpose to your `foo()` function to make sure it works.

```
#pragma once
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

template <typename T>
struct bar {
    __device__ __host__ T operator()(T t1, T t2)
    {
        return t1 + t2;
    }
};

template <template <typename> class Operator, typename T>
__global__ void fooKernel(T t1, T t2, T* t3)
{
    Operator<T> op;
    *t3 = op(t1, t2);
}

template <template <typename> class Operator, typename T>
T foo(T t1, T t2)
{
    T* t3_d;
    T t3_h;
    cudaMalloc(&t3_d, sizeof(*t3_d));
    fooKernel<Operator><<<1, 1>>>(t1, t2, t3_d);
    cudaMemcpy(&t3_h, t3_d, sizeof(*t3_d), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(t3_d);
    return t3_h;
}
```

#### gpu.cu

This file only instantiates the `foo()` function to make sure it will be available for linking:

```
#include "gpu.cuh"

template int foo<bar>(int, int);
```

#### cpu.cpp

In this plain C++ source file, we need to make sure we do not get the template instantiations, as that would give a compile error. Instead we only forward declare the struct `bar` and the function `foo`. The code looks like this:

```
#include <cstdio>

template <template <typename> class Operator, typename T>
T foo(T t1, T t2);

template <typename T>
struct bar;

int main()
{
    printf("%d \n", foo<bar>(3, 4));
}
```

#### Makefile

This will put the code all together into an executable:

```
.PHONY: clean all
all: main

clean:
        rm -f *.o main

main: gpu.o cpu.o
        g++ -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 $^ -lcudart -o $@

gpu.o: gpu.cu
        nvcc -c -arch=sm_20 $< -o $@

cpu.o: cpu.cpp
        g++ -c $< -o $@
```

Device code is compiled by `nvcc`, host code by `g++` and it all gets linked by `g++`. Upon running you see the beautiful result:

```
7
```

The key thing to remember here is that kernel launches and kernel definitions have to be in the `.cu` files that are compiled by `nvcc`. For future reference, I will also leave this link here, on [separation of linking and compilation with CUDA](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/separate-compilation-linking-cuda-device-code/).

Comment: Can you explain the need/the importance of the template-within-a-template you used?

Comment: It is not important, it just simplifies writing. This way you don't have to pass a specific instantiation of the template to the function `foo<bar<int> >` (need the space between the angle brackets pre c++11), but you can simply use `foo<bar>`. The whole thing would work with normal template parameters too.

Comment: Could I trouble you to link to somewhere explaining this point in more detail?

Comment: I would have to redirect you to [this so question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761/what-are-some-uses-of-template-template-parameters-in-c) or the *template template parameters* section of [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters).