# C++ error with template function prototype in same file as function - how to resolve?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand function templates when used in function prototypes in C++ better.  I'll jump right into my question, this works:

```
// my_prog.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename Num1Type, typename Num2Type>
auto myAdd(Num1Type num1, Num2Type num2)
{
  return num1 + num2;
}

int main()
{
  int a1 = 2;
  int a2 = 2;
  
  int result1 = myAdd(a1, a2);
  
  std::cout << "\n" << "result1 = " << result1 << "\n";
  
  double b1 = 2.2;
  double b2 = 2.2;
  
  double result2 = myAdd(b1, b2);

  std::cout << "\n" << "result2 = " << result2 << "\n";

  int c1 = 2;
  float c2 = 2.2;

  double result3 = myAdd(c1, c2);

  std::cout << "\n" << "result3 = " << result3 << "\n";


  return 0;
}
```

[image]

this does not:

```
// my_prog.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// function prototypes
template <typename Num1Type, typename Num2Type>
auto myAdd(Num1Type num1, Num2Type num2);

int main()
{
  int a1 = 2;
  int a2 = 2;
  
  int result1 = myAdd(a1, a2);
  
  std::cout << "\n" << "result1 = " << result1 << "\n";
  
  double b1 = 2.2;
  double b2 = 2.2;
  
  double result2 = myAdd(b1, b2);

  std::cout << "\n" << "result2 = " << result2 << "\n";

  int c1 = 2;
  float c2 = 2.2;

  double result3 = myAdd(c1, c2);

  std::cout << "\n" << "result3 = " << result3 << "\n";


  return 0;
}

template <typename Num1Type, typename Num2Type>
auto myAdd(Num1Type num1, Num2Type num2)
{
  return num1 + num2;
}
```

[image]

As you can see I'm using HackerRank CodePair as my editor.

I've read some information on how C++ templates work when function prototypes are used, for example:

[Template and prototype in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64704802/template-and-prototype-in-class)

[Prototyping a template function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639048/prototyping-a-template-function-in-c)

[Why doesn't this template function prototype work properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46637652/why-doesnt-this-template-function-prototype-work-properly)

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl

But I'm still not sure how to change the 2nd program above to get past the error.  Any suggestions?  Is this even possible?

Comment: Please post the errors as a formatted text, not a picture.

Answer (score 1):

`auto` is deduced from a `return` statement. The function declaration doesn't have a `return` hence is unable to deduce `auto`. You can guide the compiler

```
template <typename Num1Type, typename Num2Type>
auto myAdd(Num1Type num1, Num2Type num2) -> decltype(num1 + num2);
```

After that you will get linker errors, but it's another question.