# The problem in understanding c++ syntax related to c++ class definition

Tags: c++, class, oop, templates

I was reading a application source and I've faced with thing like this:

```
class A
{

};

template<>
class B<A>
{

};
```

the problem is that I can't understand `class B<A>` meaning.
What does this mean?

Comment: It's a [template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) of a [class template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template)

Comment: Do you know what a template is?

Comment: The class B is a template class, probably class B has some implementation that is common to a certain type of class/objects. Look up class templates in the link http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28354752/template-vs-template-without-brackets-whats-the-difference

Comment: [This book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) should be your next stop. Do not learn C++ from scratch by reading source code. It may work with other languages, but here it will only lead to frustration and difficulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that class `B` has been declared as a template, and now you have a template specialization. Just like in sewing, this means that `B` won't work on its own, but requires another class, here `A`, to work.

It is a new type and then `B` will use `A` as kind of thread (to continue the sewing analogy) wherever the original type (that you didn't show) was.

You may want to have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates

Comment: Sewing? Just like in sewing?

Comment: I don't get your sewing analogy. Is `B` the needle and `A` the thread or something?

Comment: Should have gone with baking.  A template is a generic recipe for making cookies and a specialization is either a special version of the recipe or a special cookie cutter.

Comment: In sewing, you also have a template, and then you apply this template with some fabric. And sometimes, due tot the fabric, you need to specialize it.